# How many characters/pages could WordStar hold on a typical CP/M machine?

Tags: cp-m, wordstar

I was looking at the [Atari Word Processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_Word_Processor) which could hold only about one or two pages in 48k memory due to it requiring DOS to be loaded along with the relatively large program itself.

That led me to wonder... on a typical Z80 or 8080 CP/M machine of the era, how much could WordStar hold?

Comment: I don’t have the answer, but WordStar would swap text out to disk if it couldn’t fit a document in memory, avoiding the problems Atari Word Processor had (as long as the current disk had enough available storage).

Comment: And “typical”?  More interesting with the full 64 kb

Comment: Speedscript also runs on Atari 8-bit machines. I think it allowed over 20 pages on a C64.

Comment: One of the killer features for a text editor, before the era of virtual memory anyway, was being able to edit documents larger than physical memory.  There's quite a few ways to manage it.  WordStar was such an editor, and I have little doubt that accounted for some its popularity.  (Not just as a word processor, it was very popular as a general-purpose editor too.)

Comment: I don’t know about the CP/M version, but at least the DOS version swapped not just data but also code. It had a couple of  files with extension OVL (overlay) and it swapped code in and out of memory from them (I think it swapped fragments rather than the whole OVL file but I’m not sure).

Comment: @RETRAC - to me, it doesn't seem like a "killer feature" so much as "basic required functionality".

Comment: @another-dave but it wasn't universal.  I certainly had files too big for MSDOS's `EDIT`, and had to use Norton Editor

Comment: And yet a 1970-ish text editor I used could operate with only 640 words (3840 characters) of storage to hold both the original and modified text.  Software design involves tradeoffs, and in this case "sequentially processing parts of the file" is a better tradeoff than "cannot edit at all".

Comment: @another-dave: Programs that were designed to work with a file loaded into memory were often more efficient for working with the files they could handle than would be programs that needed to support swapping data to and from disk.  An important point to consider is that on many systems, if someone was typing when it became necessary to write data to disk, there would be no way to avoid losing keystrokes.  In theory, I would think it would be possible (and not even excessively difficult) to write disk routines for something like an Apple II that would poll for a keystroke every time they...

Comment: ...saw a header for something other than the sector they needed (which would mean that code could, without loss of performance, spend about 10ms doing something else before looking for the next sector) but I don't know if any word processoors or text editors for the Apple II did such a thing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I wrote at least one manual of about 20 pages in about 1986 on CP/M WordStar 3.3, using a Microsoft [Z80 Softcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-80_SoftCard) plugged into an Apple IIe. That would swap text in or out to floppy disk from time to time, especially when you jumped to the far end of the document, but it was perfectly usable. The maximum size in-memory wasn't terribly meaningful with WordStar, it was intended to swap and did it automatically and reliably.

Maximum document size would have been half the available space on the floppy that held the document by default. You could put the swap space on another drive, but that wasn't the default. If you had a big hard disc, there was also a limit of 8MiB, set by the CP/M file system.

The Apple II 5.25" floppies had pretty limited capacity (143 KiB, not altered by CP/M IIRC). I was working with about 65 columns, and printing on an [Apple Dot Matrix Printer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Dot_Matrix_Printer), probably using about 55 lines per page, for about 3.5KiB per page, so 20-page documents would have taken about half a floppy's capacity and would have been close to the default limit on this setup.

With higher-capacity drives, maximum document size would increase. I don't know what "typical" floppy capacity for CP/M would be: the Apple II version is the only one I used.

Comment: Though the question is asking explicitly not about maximum document size (which I guess would be maximum file size on the floppy/harddisk, and having multiple documents e.g. for each chapter wasn't a problem), but about pages in memory. For whatever reason.

Comment: @dirkt: That's not very meaningful with WordStar.

Comment: @dirkt in practice with WordStar the maximum document size was *half* the available space on disk (because of the additional swap files).

Comment: I didn't ask the question, and yes, it's not very meaningful. It's up to the OP to refine it.

Comment: Ahh, I did not realize it did swapping! So combined with the answer below, it seems you had perhaps 10 kB of free room in RAM, and it swapped in and out of that.

Comment: @Maury a 64K system would have more than 10K of free room: the 45K requirement includes room for text editing. WordStar would refuse to start if it only had room to load itself.

Comment: @StephenKitt Does the swap file have to be on the same floppy? I don't remember, but if not, you can also use a full floppy, if you have two floppy drives :-) (Or 8 MB on a harddisk, if you have such a large harddisk).

Comment: @dirkt, the document’s swap file was always created on the same disk as the document. Placement was not configurable. On a two-floppy system you kept WordStar in one disk and put the document on the other.

Comment: @dirkt lots and lots of KayPro 10 systems were sold.

Comment: Looking at the Wordstar 3.3 manual (found via Google), it was possible to overcome the 50% disk space limit by using two disks. It also mentions an 8 Mb file system limit on document size (there were CP/M machines with hard drives this big, but not exactly typical).

Answer (score 6):

According to the installation manual at http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/microPro/Wordstar_3.0/Wordstar_3.0_Installation_Manual_May81.pdf WordStar requires 45 kb to be able to work on a 80x24 display.

A 64 kb machine has 19 kb more, so at least that.

Comment: Same manual, page 1-1, about using on a single floppy system: "... and leave two times the size of the biggest file you will want to
edit as unused space on the disk. "

Comment: That said it is an astonishing program. You should try writing a non-trivial document in it (even though you might want a faster disk).

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen what's so special about it?

Comment: @OmarL The same as for next to all early implementations of anything - it was the jump from none to one. You will hear all the same stories about Apple Writer, despite it's cruel way of display and input. It's the revelation of editing a text in full screen, jumping around inserting and deleting effortless.

Comment: @Raffzahn no. The block commands with anchors lean much better toward how some authors work. Game of thrones author used it as long as he could. Opinions: https://youtu.be/X5REM-3nWHg

Comment: @OmarL The key commands were exceptionally well thought out giving a way of working lost to time, as WordPerfect conquered the dos world. Had Word targeted wordstar instead our ways of working today would be very different.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Not sure what point you want to make by initiating a A is better than B discussion. There have been books written on the C64, so some author using some package doesn't make it better or worse. (Not to mention, that according to your link RRM used DOS and Wordstar 4.0. not really the one the question asks about. There are _huge_ differences between original 8080 wordstar and much later 4.0 on DOS)

Comment: @Raffzahn I am not as such saying A is better than B, but _different_, and if you don't point out there is a difference people won't understand why some users used it as long as they possibly could, and this is about how you navigate non-linearly.  We are SO used to the "mark region and do something with it now" mindset, where the Wordstar anchors allowed you to do this in what order you wanted, plus the ^Q-number shortcuts.   So this is not about being able to work full screen - numerous editors existed for that - but _how_ you worked full screen.

Comment: @Raffzahn  Much like "we have Microsoft Teams, why do you like Slack better? They can do the same!?"

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen So, our point is that no one did use any other program for a longer time? A rather doubtful claim, isn't it? People always tend to stay with the tools they have and know (can give plenty examples myself - plus fights with users of older software of mine). So length of usage is not any argument for either. It's what they had first and WS was a major player a early on. The very same was seen with users of other programs - including the quirky Apple Writer. Your further argumentation is exactly about _'A is better than B because of feature C'_

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen And yes, it's about using full screen - or in fact a word processor at all. Take A.C.Clarke, another well known writer and Wordstar user, may be an even better example, as he did stick with his Kaypro II for a very long time, way beyond the availability and improvements of DOS Wordstar. Why? Because it was the tool he used, and it wasn't a switch from rational switch some 'inferior' software to WS, but from a typewriter. It could have been any computer and program that brought the advancements of a word processor - it was Wordstar because it run on a portable.

Comment: @Raffzahn i fully agree that this is most likely the first word processor learned after the typewriter, but then why not upgrade when more powerful programs came along? If you just use it as a typewriter, then what is the difference?  That said, this is about saying that “In the old days program A did things differently, notably C.  you way want to try it to possibly learn something now you know B.”  I’m very much not saying it is better, just that some people liked it for writing book sized prose,  as you know this is about teaching to the young ones.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, WordStar swapped memory to disk during operation, so the document size was not dependent upon free RAM (outside of a basic free RAM requirement for the program). The larger the free RAM, the less often  you had to swap to disk.

That suggests that the maximum document size was pegged to somewhere around 1/2 of disk capacity, since the disk has to hold both the original document, and the swapped version.

Mind, the swap file could be stored on a separate disk. In a typical 2 Disk system, you'd probably have the document in the B drive, and the CP/M, WordStar install in the A drive. With the swap file on the A drive, you'd have all that free space over and above CP/M and WordStar, which is quite likely less than half the disk, for the swap file for the larger file on the B drive.

256K was a common disk size, obviously densities improved, but 256K is good enough for a ball park. You could probably get a working system with 180K free on the disk (that's a guess). A page of text is 80 characters (10 characters per inch, 8 inches wide) by 60 lines (6 lines per inch, 10 inches long). Go double spaced, that 30 lines. That's 80 * 30, 2400 characters per page. 180K / 2400, 76 pages.

Ample space for a wide range of tasks. If you're working on a book, however, probably going to be 1 disk per chapter.

All told, though, beats a typewriter.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that at least when talking about the CP/M version of WordStar it wasn't uncommon to use 8" floppy drives with CP/M systems so the max filesize could be quite a bit larger than with 5.25" disks (up to 1.2MB for DS/DD drives available from 1977 on).

Comment: Comments in the accepted answer say that the swap file is automatically created on the disk with the data file.  Evidence of configurable nature would be very helpful.